# Soft assertion and mock methods test failure

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I`m following this tutorial: http://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-5-mock-methods-and-overriding-constructors/ . A great tutorial for learn how works PHPUnit.

But I´m not able to understand because the test not pass.

The failure is:

```
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

At this part of code:

```
        $badCode->expects($this->once())
            ->method('checkPassword')
            ->with($password);
```

But this is not possible because the next soft assertion runs inside checkPassword method and pass the test.

```
        $badCode->expects($this->once())
            ->method('callExit');
```

It fails because is a mock method and the behaviour is different? Or the code is wrong?

I attach all the files for easy understanding, it is a small example.

Console

```
PHPUnit 3.7.18 by Sebastian Bergmann.

FYOU SHALL NOT PASS............

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) phpUnitTutorial\Test\BadCodeTest::testAuthorizeExitsWhenPasswordNotSet
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:checkPassword> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.


FAILURES!
Tests: 13, Assertions: 14, Failures: 1.
```

BadCode.php

```
<?php

namespace phpUnitTutorial;

class BadCode
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(array $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function authorize($password)
    {
        if ($this->checkPassword($password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function checkPassword($password)
    {
        if (empty($user['password']) || $user['password'] !== $password) {
            echo 'YOU SHALL NOT PASS';
            $this->callExit();
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function callExit()
    {
        exit;
    }
}
```

BadCodeTest.php

```
<?php

namespace phpUnitTutorial\Test;

class BadCodeTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testAuthorizeExitsWhenPasswordNotSet()
    {
        $user = array('username' => 'jtreminio');
        $password = 'foo';

        $badCode = $this->getMockBuilder('phpUnitTutorial\BadCode')
            ->setConstructorArgs(array($user))
            ->setMethods(array('callExit'))
            ->getMock();

        $badCode->expects($this->once())
            ->method('checkPassword')
            ->with($password);

        $badCode->expects($this->once())
            ->method('callExit');

        $this->expectOutputString('YOU SHALL NOT PASS');

        $badCode->authorize($password);
    }
}
```

Someone can help me? Thanks!

**Update**

The author of the blog updated the tutorial with the solution.
Can't do any assertions against mock methods, only stubs.

BadCode.php

```
<?php

namespace phpUnitTutorial;

class BadCode
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(array $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function authorize($password)
    {
        if ($this->checkPassword($password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function checkPassword($password)
    {
        if (empty($this->user['password']) || $this->user['password'] !== $password) {
            echo 'YOU SHALL NOT PASS';
            $this->callExit();
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function callExit()
    {
        exit;
    }
}
```

BadCodeTest.php

```
<?php

namespace phpUnitTutorial\Test;

class BadCodeTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testAuthorizeExitsWhenPasswordNotSet()
    {
        $user = array('username' => 'jtreminio');
        $password = 'foo';

        $badCode = $this->getMockBuilder('phpUnitTutorial\BadCode')
            ->setConstructorArgs(array($user))
            ->setMethods(array('callExit'))

        $badCode->expects($this->once())
            ->method('callExit');

        $this->expectOutputString('YOU SHALL NOT PASS');

        $badCode->authorize($password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

author here - I fudged that part up, and AppFog (my host) is having issues with free accounts (mine) so I can't update it right now.

Also, yes it should be `$this->user` in `checkPassword()`

Comment: Ok, I wait the solution! Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Hey @Sangar82 the code has been updated. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: You have deleted $badCode->expects($this->once())->method('checkPassword')->with($password); But why? It seems that this  should work, but I don´t understand because fails the test before delete those lines

Comment: @Sangar82 I made a mistake and forgot you can't do any assertions against mock methods, only stubs.

I think allowing some `->expects()` on mocks would be very helpful though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I hope that you follow with the Unit Testing Tutorial. Great Work!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a method in `setMethods` :

```
->setMethods(array('callExit'))
```

You need to add `checkPassword` too if you want to check if it is called.

Comment: I thought this too (and it might be correct) but the example still won't work

Comment: This example is for learning the difference between mock and stub methods. In the example, checkPassword isn't int setMethods because is a Mock Method and callExit a Stub Method

Comment: @Sangar82 Yes, you are right. I've learned already... Thanks for the tutorial. Now I understand your code, and it looks ok. You need `callExit()` as a stub as it otherwise would end the testsuite (using exit). Will need deeper testing. Which PHPUnit version are you using? But you should one thing (although) it does not belong directly to the problem: Use `$this->user` instead of `$user` in `checkPassword()`

Comment: @hek2mgl I´m using 3.7.18. The classname is BadCode, not expect many more about the example, but explains very well  the difference between stub method and mock method. If remove those lines the test pass. It seems all correct, but not pass the test, and this has me intrigued